# A robust and flexible alternative to doxygen supporting C++

Tags: gratis, open-source, software-development, c++, documentation-generator

I need to generate documentation for a C++ project of mine (and soon perhaps also for additional ones). So far I've looked into doxygen, and even though it seems popular, I've had some issues with it (the details of which I won't go into here; some have been resolved). Since I'm not particularly attached to it - despite its apparent popularity - I want to consider some alternatives.

Now, 7 years ago there was a question on StackOverflow on exactly that:

[Doxygen Alternatives for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2323074/1593077)

but the answers are by now dated, so I'm reasking the same question, here and now.

Requirements:

- Libre
- Gratis
- Multiplatform, supporting at least Linux and Windows
- Flexible to a similar level as doxygen or more
- Actively maintained
- Non-negligible user base

Comment: If you "won't go into the details here", then it's going to be difficult to help you

Comment: @Mawg: It was mostly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43093051/1593077), but that won't help you much I think...

Comment: But that got solved. So why not use DoxyGen? Just curious

Comment: @Mawg: The fact that it behaved that way gave me a hunch I might want something else. Also, why _should_ I use doxygen, other than I've heard of it? It's not like a I have positive experience with it.

Comment: Why not at least give it a try?  There are a lot of people out there who are positive about it. They  can’t all be wrong. Plus, it has been actively maintained and developed for many tears, and Dimitri is very helpful  Since the home page starts “Doxygen is the de facto standard tool for generating documentation from annotated C++ sources”, surely it is worth a try. And, that it continues “but it also supports other popular programming languages is a big plus point for me.

Comment: But, wait, you had a problem, which was solved, so you presumably *have* used it to generate documentation from your code. If you can tell us what specific features are missing, then we can try to help you.

Comment: @Mawg: Who said I'm not giving it a try? I just don't want to give _only_ doxygen a try.

Comment: Then try others ***and*** DoxyGen (if it helps, there is probably a reason that it is the industry standard)

Comment: Since the only alternative suggested so far is Sphinx-Doc, take a look at [What are the main differences of Sphinx and Doxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571849/what-are-the-main-differences-of-sphinx-and-doxygen) and Wikipedia's [Comparison of documentation generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators)

Comment: the stackoverflow.com link... now returns "page not found". admins are getting a little out of hand there.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: The question was deleted, but the admis/moderators there should have moved the answers here. Maybe we can do that?

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: See my new answer...

Comment: what is with all the useless comments about telling him to use doxygen when he said he wanted alternatives? +1 for one more useless comment. Thanks for asking the question and wtf did they delete the other question for

Answer (score 7):

Personally I would strongly recommend taking a look at [Sphinx-Doc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org) which was written for the Python documentation but is applicable to other systems as well.

- Produces great looking documents with multiple themes in  multiple formats
- Can generate from multiple programming language, e.g. C++ with the C++ [domain](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#id2)
- Can be integrated with build systems including make, Jenkins, etc.

Addressing your points:

- Libre ***Fully Open Source***
- Gratis ***Yes***
- Multiplatform, supporting at least Linux and Windows ***Yes*** *Python based so runs just about anywhere [Multi-platform Installation Instructions](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/install.html)*
- Flexible to a similar level as doxygen or more ***Yes*** *Personally I find it more flexible as it allows a mixture of auto-generated and pre-written, in ReStructuredText, documentation.*
- Actively maintained ***Yes*** *At the time of writing rev 1.5.3 was released 2017-02-26 just over a month ago*
- Non-negligible user base ***Yes*** -  *[Read The Docs](http://readthedocs.org/) supports it to start with & lots of examples [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/examples.html)*

Note that for Automatically generating nice looking documentation from C/C++ source code you can combine Sphinx *for the document generation* with [doxyGen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) *for information extraction to XML* and [breathe](https://breathe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) acting as a bridge between them.

Comment: Sphinx does not support autogenerated docs for C or C++. That is, you need to maintain your entire API and documentation in ReST files parallel to your code. Big risk for typos, things to get out of sync, etc.

Comment: @detly Added information on the breathe extension that allows auto-generation _via doxygen_ from the code.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'd seen *breathe* mentioned elsewhere but misunderstood what role it played here. After doing a bit more research it seems there's also some LLVM Clang based autogen plugins for Sphinx that are in development but might eventually fill that gap too.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>(I've salvaged several answers from the now-deleted StackOverflow question page:)</sub>

#### Doc++

You could try [DOC++](http://docpp.sourceforge.net/) but it may be even uglier.

### cldoc

There is an open source alternative to doxygen out there called [cldoc](http://jessevdk.github.io/cldoc/).

It can handle both C and C++ and is based on clang. The most interesting features it claims to offer:

- Uses clang to robustly parse even the most complex C++ projects without additional effort from the user.
- Uses markdown for documentation formatting.
- Uses a simple format for documenting your code.
- Supports cross-referencing in documentation.
- Generates a single file, javascript based web application to render the documentation.
- Lightning fast client-side searching using a pregenerated search index.

#### NaturalDocs

[NaturalDocs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) has its warts, but the output is decent and the markup is effortless.

#### NetBeans

If you're interested in tracing big project, then I would suggest c++ version of Netbeans which can dynamically generate nice call graphs ( look for 'Show Call Graph' feature ).

#### Doxypress

[DoxyPress](http://www.copperspice.com/documentation-doxypress.html) is a modern replacement for Doxygen.

Answer (score -1):

It may not meet your requirements but [standardese](https://github.com/standardese/standardese) seems worth mentioning.

As of 2022, only [Doxypress](http://www.copperspice.com/documentation-doxypress.html) and standardese seem to be alternatives to Doxygen improved for C++.
Doxpress is a fork of Doxygen at version 1.8.8 which aims to support other languages as well.

See GitHub pages for latest activities:
[standardese](https://github.com/standardese/standardese)
[Doxypress](https://github.com/copperspice/doxypress)

I haven't tried any of them, so any feedback is warmly welcome.

Comment: Please write a little more about it - how it differs from, or is similar to, doxygen.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! If it does not meet the requirements, how is it an answer then? And why is it worth mentioning if it doesn't fit?

Comment: It is worth mentioning because as of 2022, only Doxypress and standardese seem to be alternatives to Doxygen improved for C++, where the latter is not mentioned at all. Feel free to improve the post, or create a new answer based on your experience.